# Communicating Rust Lifetimes for Type Parameters

Tags: rust, lifetime, type-parameter

I'm working on a simple complex number example, and trying to implement ref-value/value-ref operations as follows:

```
use std::ops::*;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Complex<T: Sized + Clone> {
    pub re: T,
    pub im: T,
}

// Ref-Ref Multiplication
impl<'a, 'b, T: Sized + Clone> Mul<&'b Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Mul<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        panic!("// Details irrelevant")
    }
}

// Ref-Value Multiplication
impl<'a, 'b, T: Sized + Clone> Mul<Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    T: 'static,
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Mul<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        let t = &rhs;
        self.mul(t)
    }
}
```

The ref-ref implementation works, and from what I understand it it takes in two references of differing lifetimes, and returns a complex value-type. The ref-value part is where I'm having an issue; When I compile, the error is that `rhs` doesn't live long enough. I believe I know why this is already, and that is that T could hold a reference (either direct or indirectly) to rhs when the value is returned, thus `rhs` goes out of scope, but `T` could hold a reference to it still.

My question is how to communicate that `T` will not hold some reference to `rhs` in some shape or form.

Some notes on things that I've tried so far or looked at:

1. Changed the lifetime specification on either Mul implementation.
2. Tried lifetime-inheritence, but this specifieds a reference held by `T` will live at least as long as `T`, so I think I need something more in the lines of "at most."
3. Looked at other implementations; Either does not implement the case, or just uses clone to bypass the issue.

Comment: Probably you should derive `Clone` for `Complex` and then implement the ops for `Complex` instead of `&Complex`. This doesn't just bypass the issue, it's often faster than references for a small struct like this.

Comment: I'd even go one step further and derive `Copy` for the complex number type, so you don't even have to clone explicitly.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks, that's actually what I intended to write! (`Copy`, not `Clone`) :)

Comment: Your constraints on `&'a T` are unnecessary. In the end you are going to copy the `T` out of the other `Complex<T>` and move them into a new `Complex<T>`. There isn't a way to reference the original `T` here, so there is no point considering operations on `&T`.

Comment: You look like you want impl [AddAssign](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html).

Comment: I mentioned I was aware of the Clone/copy solution. Also note that the structure is not necessarily small. I could place an arbitrary precision float in there. That's why I'm trying to add this case to the value-value Mul so that if one knows that ref-ref operations are fast for T, then they can take advantage of it. Lastly, I don't necessarily copy any of the T's out of the Complex. In the //details irrelevant section it's all handled with ref-ref operations on the parts of each complex.

Comment: @Nim As a side note, adding `Sized` as a trait bound to a type parameter is redundant, since all type parameters get an implicit `Sized` bound.  You can use `T: ?Sized` to remove that implicit bound, but `T: Sized` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I see. I remember a long while ago I had issues with leaving that off. Was that changed at some point (mind you, last I used Rust was probably a year ago). Thanks!

Comment: @Nim No, this did not change recently.  Note that _type parameters_ have an implicit `Sized` bound, but the `Self` type of a trait doesn't, so writing `trait A: Sized` actually makes a difference.

Comment: @Stargateur That's a good workaround also; Using MulAssign can be used in conjunction of cloning to maintain a minimal number of allocations (I'm assuming the case that T is possible a large structure with clones being bad), which should keep the same work done for allocation. This also is very helpful with division, as the lifetime specification is much more difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Peter Hall in the comments, the easiest solution is to derive `Copy` for your complex type, and implement the operations for values.  For the ref-ref implementations and the ref-val implementations, you can then simply dereference the references and use the val-val implementation.

If you want to make the approach you started work, you need higher-rank trait bounds:

```
use std::ops::*;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Complex<T: Clone> {
    pub re: T,
    pub im: T,
}

// Ref-Ref Multiplication
impl<'a, 'b, T: Clone> Mul<&'b Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Mul<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: Sub<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex {
            re: &self.re * &rhs.re - &self.im * &rhs.im,
            im: &self.re * &rhs.im + &self.im * &rhs.re,
        }
    }
}

// Ref-Value Multiplication
impl<'a, T: Clone> Mul<Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: for<'b> Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: for<'b> Mul<&'b T, Output = T>,
    &'a T: for<'b> Sub<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        let t = &rhs;
        self.mul(t)
    }
}
```

In your version, the lifetime `'b` in the ref-value implementation is chosen by the user of the trait.  Since the user could use any lifetime for `'b`, `rhs` would need static lifetime for your code to be valid. What you want instead is that `*'a T` satisfies the given trait bounds for *any* given lifetime `'b`, which is exactly what HRTBs are for.

An alternative, less repetitive way of writing the trait bounds for the second implementation is this:

```
impl<'a, T: Clone> Mul<Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    Self: for<'b> Mul<&'b Complex<T>, Output = Complex<T>>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        self.mul(&rhs)
    }
}
```

Comment: HRTB are not necessary here. All of the lifetimes here are known at the point of calling the `mul` method.

Comment: Yeah, the HRTB's were what I needed. Been so long I had forgotten about them. Thanks! Just noting I already had the value-value stuff done. Just not shown as that was trivial, and I have reasons for not doing it that way (mentioned in reply to the question comments).

Comment: @PeterHall I don't think so. The lifetime of the local variable `t` isn't known at that time.

Comment: @Nim I added a more concise way of writing the trait bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in numeric types implement these permutations using a [macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/internal_macros.rs.html). Doing it by hand, I'd start with the case where you are multiplying two values, rather than any references, and make sure that your `Complex` struct is `Copy`:

```
impl<T: Copy> Mul<Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    T: Mul<T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need any constraints on `&T` - you can't return references to `T` anyway, so you are going to have to copy them, which is why I've specified `T: Copy`.

The rest of the implementations are now straightforward and can delegate to the simplest case:

```
impl<'a, T: Copy> Mul<Complex<T>> for &'a Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    T: Mul<T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        (*self).mul(rhs)
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Copy> Mul<&'a Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    T: Mul<T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'a Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        self.mul(*rhs)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Copy> Mul<&'a Complex<T>> for &'b Complex<T>
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T>,
    T: Sub<T, Output = T>,
    T: Mul<T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'a Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        (*self).mul(*rhs)
    }
}
```

Comment: The clone/copy method is something I've seen done in other implementations, and something I was aware of. I have a few reasons for why I'm wanting to avoid that, primarily if T is a more complex structure (e.g. arbitrary precision float); in case ref-ref operations are faster on those. Also a quick question, as you mentioned I can't return reference to T; could you elaborate upon that? Is it not possible for T to be structure which could contain a reference of T? Something like  `struct A<'a> (Option<&'a A>)` I assumed that's why my code wasn't compiling unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Nim If you want to return a reference, it would need to point to a value that existed before the`mul()` method was called; you can't return a reference to a new value you compute inside the method.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's why I thought the error was occurring. I wanted some clarification, because it was worded as references in general couldn't be returned, hence my example. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something subtle, other than the lifetime being too short to be acceptable.